# How to respond to login entries in a node js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, httprequest

I have a website with a login form (username and password) and want to receive these inputs in a node js server file, where I will later use them as an object for a database query etc.

I want to know the best way of sending and receiving/dealing with this information. At the moment the form uses a "get" method, and the node js server file uses query string to parse the inputs into an object. I can do this and obtain the parameters; below is a code sample:

HTML:

```
        <form id = "login" method="get" action="https://localhost:8443/index.html">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="log in" class="button"/><br />
        </form>
```

Node JS example:

```
    var QS = require('querystring');
    var params = QS.parse(require('url').parse(request.url).query);
```

The only issue here is using the "get" method, which makes the entered fields (including password) visible in the URL. Is this a suitable approach in general?

I have also looked at using "post" as the method but could not find a way of parsing the query from the body of the request.

One approach that may be useful but I am unfamiliar with is using AJAX requests and responses through my script.js file.

Can anyone offer any helpful solutions?

Thanks!